# Where to buy unlocked smartphone in Japan?

Tags: japan, cellphones, recommendations

I am thinking about buying a smartphone while in Tokyo.

Do you have any physical store (I leave on Monday morning) to recommend?

I've already been to Yodobashi, where they showed me about 15 models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

( Yod**O**bashi, not Yod**A**bashi )

Yodobashi would be my first choice, unless you want an iPhone. Bic is more-or-less the same as Yodobashi, just the music is more annoying.

If you know which model you want, Amazon.co.jp is another good choice.

Do check that it explicitly says "unlocked" on the box. The Japanese mobile carriers generally do everything possible to keep you from taking your money elsewhere.

The reason I said "unless you want an iPhone" is service. Android phones are cheap enough that if it breaks after you leave Japan it's not worth fixing. iPhones start at US$600. Get them from the Apple online store, which also gets you worldwide warranty service.

Neither Bic nor Yodobashi want to see you again if you have problems with your purchase.

Comment: Also, while I think it was possible when this answer was written, currently the only way to get a new unlocked iPhone in Japan is at a retail Apple store or from the Apple Store online.  Not even the Apple sub-store inside Yodobashi will sell an iPhone that is not tied to one of the big three carriers.